# Remove session data in database-backed session in django after clearing browser history

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks, django-sessions

After i clear my browser history the **session key** and data that was added to the table `django_session` (session engine is database-backed by mysql) for the session remains and for subsequent requests a new 'session key' is added. In a situation where users clear their history frequently this table will grow inadvertently. Using `clearsessions` command doesn't remove the rows because the expiry date has not yet been reached. How do i overcome this issue if the expiry date is large? Is there some setting wrongly set up?

Comment: You can't. There is no way for Django to know that the user has deleted their session key. You will just have to wait until the expiry date is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way but highly inefficient since it requires iterating over all of the existing Sessions. You can use signals to catch post_save of Session model and then delete all of the existing Sessions of this user except the new one (I am not sure if this is what you want, because it will delete all of the sessions, not just the cleared one) .

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=Session)
def save_session(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user_id = instance.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
    # Get all sessions excluding current session
    sessions = Session.objects.exclude(session_key=instance.session_key)

    # Iterate over all sessions and decode them
    for session in sessions:
        session_user_id = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
        # If the session belongs to user, delete it
        if session_user_id == user_id:
            session.delete()
```

Comment: User won't be able to log in from multiple devices.

Comment: @zahlen As i said, it clears all the sessions but the new one. So, yes the user won't be able to login from multiple devices. Basically, there is no other way.